# Understanding what $XI_n - M$ is

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

The following text from Serre's *Matrices: Theory and Applications* is confusing me.

> [image]

Serre considers $XI_n-M$ as  a matrix with entries in $K[X]$, which is perfectly fine. Right after this, he substitutes the indeterminate $X$ with a matrix $N$. To my understanding, doing so requires that we consider $XI_n-M$ as a polynomial with coefficients in a commutative ring contained in $M_n(K)$. A natural choice for this commutative subring is the ring spanned by $M$ and $I_n$. But then, $NI_n - M\in M_n(K)$, whereas Serre says that $NI_n - M\in M_n(A)$ where $A$ is the ring spanned by $N$ and $I_n$ (so $NI_n - M$ is a matrix whose entries are matrices themselves) ...

Can someone clarify this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good question on a point that is often overlooked. A rigorous interpretation is the following : if you have a ring morphism $f:A\to B$ then you get a morphism $f^*: M_n(A)\to M_n(B)$ (just applying $f$ to the coefficients). Now if $B$ is any $K$-algebra and $b\in B$ is any element, there is a unique $K$-algebra morphism $f_b: K[X]\to B$ sending $X$ to $b$, that you can call "evaluating $X$ at $b$ in $B$".

Then if $P_m = XI_n - M \in M_n(K[X])$, evaluating $X$ at $N$ means to take $f_N^*(P_M)$, where $f_N$ is a ring morphism from $K[X]$ to $M_n(K)$, so $f_N^*$ is a ring morphism from $M_n(K[X])$ to $M_n(M_n(K))\simeq M_{n^2}(K)$.

This is indeed what he calls $P_M(N)$. Of course, you can call $A$ the subring of $M_n(K)$ generated by $N$ and say that $f_N$ takes values in $A$ so $f_N^*$ takes values in $M_n(A)\subset M_n(M_n(K))$ but this amounts to the same.

---

This is by opposition to the (wrong) interpretation that $P_M = XI_n -M$ lives in $M_n(K)[X]$ and that evaluating $P_M$ at $N$ means to take $f_N(P_M)$ where $f_N : M_n(K)[X] \to M_n(K)$ replaces $X$ by $N$. This would at the end give $P_M(N) = NI_n - M = N-M$ ; but this is not what we mean.

Comment: I've though that $M_n(K[X])$ is canonically isomorphic to $M_n(K)[X]$.

Comment: It is. But writing it that way leads to a very different $f_N$. It's like saying that $(K[X])[Y]$ is canonically isomorphic to $(K[X])[Y]$ ; it's true, but in the first case you will naturally consider maps that send $Y$ to something, and in the second case maps that send $X$ to something. They are the same ring, but you are not emphasizing the same universal property. To clarify my claim, it is not wrong to say that $P_M$ lives in $M_n(K)[X]$, but it is wrong to say that "evaluating $P_M$ at $N$ means...".

Comment: I didn't know about $f^*$, thanks for clarification.

Comment: btw, does $f^*$ have a special name ?

Comment: Hmm, "the induced map", probably. It doesn't have a specific name, but if you know what a functor is, you can say that $M_n(-)$ is a functor, and what I called $f^*$ (the notation not completely standard, but every mathematician will understand what it means) is just $M_n(f)$.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, here is the quite brief proof of Cayley-Hamilton that follows http://imgur.com/jgNoFT9